# php capture callback responses to file

Tags: php, json, api

I'm using an API from an SMS provider (yes, it needs to be this provider so I'm stuck with it), but their documentation leaves a lot to be desired, and that includes examples and support.

I'm trying to figure out their different callbacks however I have no idea what exactly they're sending back. Is there a way to write a PHP script that captures any incoming responses to file. The responses look like this (but not exclusively), so I wanna send a couple calls (both correct and with errors) and record what I get.

```
{
   "api_job_id":"4c2478d3-aebb-4510-8720-1b479d01cfd5",
   "client_job_id":"abc123456",
   "data":[
      {
         "type":"SMS",
         "message_id":"14182390945378443202",
         "status":"SENT",
         "timestamp":1422885283,
         "micro_timestamp":1422885283477,
         "to":"XXXXXXXXX",
         "from":"CompanyA",
         "client_message_id":"2",
         "error_code":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: It's json. Use `json_decode($string, true);` to put it into an array.

Comment: As i said..i have no idea what they're sending back. this script needs to be waiting for a response as it happens anytime within a few hours (when the SMS either gives up, or gets delivered).

Comment: Have you thought about throwing the returning result into a file using `file_put_contents`?

Comment: can it put ANYTHING to file without knowing what it is? basically capture anything that is sent to the script to a text file.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say...if I know that they're gonna post to the script something like myscript.php?response={JSON}...then i know i can use the $_POST['response'] to get that json but I don't know what they're sending back. So i need something that would capture myscript.php?ANYTHING={json}

Comment: @Necrospasm of course you can write whatever the response is to a file. Is that the extent of your question?

Comment: No, I guess I made a piss-poor job at explaining. What I'm looking for (or was) is something similar to Hookbin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$logfile = dirname(__FILE__).'/SMScallback.log';  // change if necessary

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $header = 'callback_key: "' . $key . '", received: ' . gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' (UTC)'. ', contents:' . PHP_EOL;
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') >= 0) {
        $tmparray = (array)json_decode($value);
        $json = json_encode($tmparray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else  {
        $json = $value;
    }

    file_put_contents($logfile, $header . $json. PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    echo "Saved to file '$logfile'";
}

// http://www.example.com/smscallback.php?callbck1={"api_job_id":"4c2478d3-aebb-4510-8720-1b479d01cfd5","client_job_id":"abc123456","data":[{"type":"SMS","message_id":"14182390945378443202","status":"SENT","timestamp":1422885283,"micro_timestamp":1422885283477,"to":"XXXXXXXXX","from":"CompanyA","client_message_id":"2","error_code":0}]}

?>
```

The script accepts any GET parameters. It writes (appends) the GET key, the current date and time (UTC) plus the values of the GET parameters into a log file on the server. 
Note: The web server must have write privileges for the log file, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to capture requests for debugging etc, I just found Hookbin.com by sheer coincidence.